# Getting Error While doing bundle install with ruby racer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

While doing Bundle install for my app, I'm getting an error related to therubyracer (0.9.4).

This is the error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/kpvarma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling rr.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
rr.cpp:48:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
rr.cpp:151:44: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    return String::New(RSTRING_PTR(value), RSTRING_LEN(value));
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kpvarma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:674:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^
/Users/kpvarma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:670:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rr.cpp:151:44: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    return String::New(RSTRING_PTR(value), RSTRING_LEN(value));
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kpvarma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:675:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
                           ^
3 warnings generated.
compiling v8.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_array.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_callbacks.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_context.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_date.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_debug.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_exception.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_exception.cpp:15:8: warning: unused function 'segfault' [-Wunused-function]
  void segfault(int sig) {
       ^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8_external.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_external.cpp:10:9: warning: unused variable 'references' [-Wunused-variable]
  VALUE references;
        ^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8_function.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_function.cpp:24:23: error: variable length array of non-POD element type 'Handle<v8::Value>'
    Handle<Value> argv[argc];
                      ^
v8_function.cpp:36:23: error: variable length array of non-POD element type 'Handle<v8::Value>'
    Handle<Value> argv[argc];
                      ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [v8_function.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kpvarma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/therubyracer-0.9.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kpvarma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/therubyracer-0.9.4/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing therubyracer (0.9.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.9.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I amm using ruby-1.9.3-p194 on Mac.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thank you 
Regards

Comment: Building *therubyracer* is always a pain in the ass... Install the bleeding edge version with `gem install therubyracer --pre` or by putting `gem "therubyracer", "~> 0.8.2.pre"` in your *Gemfile*.

Comment: Please format your answer better.

Comment: Hi samy, thank you for the quick reply. however it throws the same error